# "Simple login page" generates 30 or more requests per refresh

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, request

I have a strange behavior in my project, a simple login page is generating 30 or more requests per update (F5). I though at first that it would be the img tags making requests, but after turning cache on the problem continued. As a test, I've tried another application using VRaptor, and the login page used only 2 requests to be drawn. So I believe that JSF shouldn't take more than 5 to draw it.

The second strange behavior is the application creating a session in the login page, although the LoginBean being Request Scoped.

I really have no clue of what's happening, someone can give me a light?

Primefaces 3.2, Servlet 2.5, Spring 3.0.5

Comment: Provide the relevant JSF code to analyse your problem.

Comment: Why don't you tell which requests exactly it are? In any way, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a list of all HTTP requests it fires per F5 (just press F12 in a modern browser and check "Network" section and copypaste or screenshot it).

Comment: @BalusC, I didn't knew that I could see the requests. I'll look at it and try to solve by myself, if I can't I'll be updating this question. Thanks.